# Laravel BadMethodCallException on delete()

Tags: laravel, eloquent, laravel-query-builder

Unable to perform delete on find(),

> BadMethodCallException Call to undefined method
> App\Models\Task::ondeletemodel().

But when using where it works.

```php
    public function delete($id)
    {
            Task::find($id)->delete(); //error
            // Task::where('id', $id)->delete(); //not error 
            session()->flash('message', 'Task Deleted Successfully.');
    }
```

Edited : here is my uuid trait:
<?php

```
namespace App\Http\Traits;

use Facades\Str;

trait UseUuid
{
    protected static function boot()
    {
        parent::boot();

        static::creating(function ($model) {
            $model->uuid = unique_str($model);
        });

        static::deleting(function ($model) 
        {
            $model->ondeletemodel($model);
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Please can you show the code for your `Task` model and also any `Observers` you've set up for it.

Comment: Please can you also show what's going in the `UseUuid` trait. Do you have an `Observer` set up for this model?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

as it shows in the error message:

In the `use App\Http\Traits\UseUuid` probably you have defined a listener to be fired on `ondeletemodel` but there is not an method named like this, in the trait or the Task Model

Comment: I have edited my question. I think it's static::deleting in boot()

Comment: so I was right, you can get rid of the ` $model->ondeletemodel($model);` line

Comment: you can get rid of the whole `static::deleting` block, since it doesn't doing anything

Comment: thank you I will try

Comment: @juniorFrogie have you tried out?

Comment: yes it works now after removed that.

Answer (score -1):

```
$tasks = Task::find($id);
$task->users->detach();
$tasks->delete();
session()->flash('message', 'Task Deleted Successfully.');
```

Comment: Please add some explanation of what the issue was and how this code solves it.